# Replace input element through a hx-swap-oob

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to add an `is-valid` class to an input element upon a successful post of a file in addition to adding a row in a table. My response looks like this:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="/images/icons/caret-right-fill.svg" alt="Right Caret" width="16.0" height="16.0">
    </td>
    <td>2022-10-26 03:03:27 +0000</td>
    <td>Big Broker</td>
    <td>Brokerage</td>
    <td>File</td>
    <td>
        <button hx-get="/import/component/import-containers/D2EA97B3-CA69-405B-8B45-F309F3DB2240" hx-target="#upload-content" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-rounded btn-sm fw-bold">View</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<input type="file" name="file" class="form-control is-valid" title="" id="id_file" required accept=".csv" hx-swap-oob="true">
```

Nothing happens after getting this response. If I remove the `input` element, the row is correctly added to my table. No error is displayed in the console. This leads me to 2 questions:

- Why is the `hx-swap-oob` not working? Is it because of some limitation on `input`?
- Considering all I want to do is to add `is-valid` to the class of the `input` after successful submission in addition of adding the row, is `hx-swap-oob` the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make shure the id of the input element is correct. ;)

Because you are using table rows here, you must enable template fragment parsing.
Set useTemplateFragments to true (not IE11 compatible):
see  https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/#oob

```
<meta name="htmx-config" content='{"useTemplateFragments":"true"}'>
```

To avoid swap-oop you could use a client site javascript function to add or remove classes.

```
(function () {
    document.body.addEventListener("evtHtmxHelper", function (evt) {
        // You can extend this to set attributes and so on
        if (evt.detail.mode === "add") {
            htmx.addClass(htmx.find("#" + evt.detail.id), evt.detail.class);
        }
        else if (evt.detail.mode === "remove") {
            htmx.removeClass(htmx.find("#" + evt.detail.id), evt.detail.class);
        }
        else {
            console.error("unkown mode");
            return;
        }
    });
})();
```

Then add a response header like this (I use aspnet core):

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("HX-Trigger-After-Swap", "{\"evtHtmxHelper\":" +
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
    {
        id = "id_file",
        mode = "add",
        className = "is-valid"
    }) + "}");
```

see https://htmx.org/reference/#response_headers

Comment: This is embarrassing, but I ignored the useTemplateFragments part because I misread it as saying "You only really need this if you care about IE 11". There were other issues with my code, but this helped be get on the right track. Thanks!